# calculate the digits of the Nth number using the given numbers

Tags: python, algorithm, numbers

I'd like to get the digits of the Nth number by using the given numbers which are 3 and 9. From these numbers, I've got the numbers like `3, 9, 33, 39, 93, 99, 333 ...` in order. So the digits of the 4th number is **2** and that of the 7th number is **3**. **What I want to do is to calculate the digits of the Nth number from this logic.** Any suggestions? Thanks.
(You may assume that N is 1000000)

+What I've found was that there are 2 1-digit numbers (=2^1), 4 2-digit numbers (=2^2), and 8 3-digit numbers(=2^3). So I tried to apply the concept of geometric sequence but wasn't able to make it.

Comment: Why "without importing additional libraries"?

Comment: Please, check [ask] and [how to ask homework questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822/4046632)

Comment: @matszwecja, most likely this is homework question with certain restrictions applied.

Comment: `given two numbers` - are they always of length 1? (really digits). Are they distinct?

Comment: @matszwecja Actually you can use any libraries but I just wanted to know the way to implement it from scratch to get the idea of solving the problem step by step.

Comment: @buran It's not homework question

Comment: @MBo yes you can assume that just use 3 and 9 in this case.

Comment: Again, you claim it is not homework question, but it sounds very much like one. Anyway - this is not code writing service. Show your code, [mre], ask question about specific question about your code. Check [ask].

Comment: Hint: Logarithms

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already know that quantity of numbers with length k is 2^k, so we can exploit this fact. Essentially this is implementation of `int(log2(n+1))` without any math libraries:

```
def nlen(n):
    lng = 0
    lcnt = 1
    overall = 0
    while overall < n:
        lcnt *= 2
        overall += lcnt
        lng += 1
    return lng
```

Comment: You can spare the variable `lcnt` by using `overall= 2 * overall + 2`.

Comment: @Yves Daoust Yes, just wanted to show dependency number length-series length - overall length

Comment: Next challenge is to do it with a single variable and shifts :-)

Answer (score 2):

Written in binary, there are `10` numbers of a single digit, `110` numbers of two digits or less, `1110` numbers of three digits or less, `11110` numbers of four digits or less... So `(2 << k)-2` numbers of `k` digits or less.

For a given `N`, it is an easy matter to find the smallest `k` that fits.